# Как выключить кнопку на форме на время выполнения Task'a?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Имеется Task, надо, чтобы на время его выполнения кнопка на форме лочилась.

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     // Тут идёт коннект к БД
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
        public async void Start()
        {
            button.IsEnabled = false;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //коннект к базе
            });

            button.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

---

Для .NET 4.0 должен подойти такой вариант:

```
    public void Start()
    {
         button.IsEnabled = false;
         Task task = ConnectToDb();

         task.ContinueWith(task1 =>
         {
             button.IsEnabled = true;

         }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    }

    private Task ConnectToDb()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //подключение к базе
        });
    }
```

Comment: А можно реализацию под 4.0 без async/await.

Comment: @user212961, обновил ответ.

Comment: @Lightness: Не, `task.Wait` заблокирует UI. Нужно `task.ContinueWith` на UI-scheduler'е.

Comment: @VladD, Подправил.